IIS10 HTTP Error 503 Event 5002 Application pool disabled automatically Windows Server 2019
I have been trying to solve a problem in IIS for several days that occurs on dates where my requests are raised.
I have an AWS-EC2 on an IIS10, which since a certain date has shown me several errors of this type:

And after several errors of this type I get error 503 with EventId 5002:
Application pool '{appPoolName}' is being automatically disabled due to a series 
of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

32-bit application support is set to false. And the Fail-Protection is with the default values.
Could you help me see what possible causes cause this error scenario? And what could I do to solve it? Should I work on errors in the application hosted on said server?

The web apps hosted in this application pool crashed the worker processes quickly for some reasons and that caused IIS to disable the pool. To resolve this you need to know what led to the crashes. If your web app developers couldn’t figure that out, you might try to open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com
